# in MERN, Response given and using useState to update new state with new fetched data, but not visually visible in my website even though logic works

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

By using console.log(responseData.places) I have checked the fetching works since I am using a hook for this and seems to work fine until I setLoadedPlaces with is the method I use to update the loadedPlaces which I later use to get the values to fill the frontend part of the website.

This is the output I get from this console.log I did and the values are correct.

```
[{…}]

0: address: "sis se puede   

busrespect: 'tu puedes', 

creator: "6384e2f543f63be1c560effa"

description: "al mundial"

id: "6384e30243f63be1c560f000"

image:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg/400px-Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg"location: {lat: -12.086158, lng: -76.898019}

title: "Peru"

__v: 0

_id: "6384e30243f63be1c560f000"[[Prototype]]:

Objectlength: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

So after this this the code I have in the frontend (SINCE the backend works properly) Let me know if you have any doubts with this logic

This is UserPlaces.js

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PlaceList from '../components/PlaceList';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useHttpClient } from '../../shared/hooks/http-hook';
import ErrorModal from '../../shared/components/UIElements/ErrorModal';
import LoadingSpinner from '../../shared/components/UIElements/LoadingSpinner';
 
const UserPlaces = () => {
    const {loadedPlaces, setLoadedPlaces} = useState();
    const {isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
    const userId = useParams().userId;
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPlaces = async () => {
          try {
            const responseData = await sendRequest(
              `http://localhost:5000/api/places/user/${userId}`
            );
            console.log(responseData.bus_stops)
            setLoadedPlaces(responseData.bus_stops);
          } catch (err) {}
        };
        fetchPlaces();
      }, [sendRequest, userId]);
 
 
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
          {isLoading && (
            <div className="center">
              <LoadingSpinner />
            </div>
          )}
          {!isLoading && loadedPlaces && <PlaceList items={loadedPlaces} />}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default UserPlaces;
```

This is Place-List.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "./PlaceList.css"
import Card from '../../shared/components/UIElements/Card'
import PlaceItem from './PlaceItem';
import Button from '../../shared/components/FormElements/Button';
 
const PlaceList = props => {
    if (props.items.length === 0) {
        return (
            <div className='place-list-center'>
                 <Card>
                <h2>No bus stops available. Be the first one to create one!</h2>
                <Button to='/places/new'> Create Bus Stop </Button>
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return (
        <ul className="place-list">
          {props.items.map(bus_stops => (
            <PlaceItem
            key={bus_stops.id}
              id={bus_stops.id}
              image={bus_stops.image}
              title={bus_stops.title}
              busrespect={bus_stops.busrespect}
              description={bus_stops.description}
              address={bus_stops.address}
              creatorId={bus_stops.creator}
              coordinates={bus_stops.location}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    };
    
    export default PlaceList;
```

This is PlaceItem.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Card from '../../shared/components/UIElements/Card';
import Button from '../../shared/components/FormElements/Button';
import Modal from '../../shared/components/UIElements/Modal';
import Map from '../../shared/components/UIElements/Map';

import {AuthContext} from '../../shared//context/auth-context'
import "./PlaceItem.css";


const PlaceItem = props => {
    const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [showMap, setShowMap] = useState(false);

    const [showConfirmModal, setShowConfirmModal] = useState(false);
    const openMapHandler = () => setShowMap(true);

    const closeMapHandler = () => setShowMap(false);

    const showDeleteWarningHandler = () => {
        setShowConfirmModal(true);
      };
    
      const cancelDeleteHandler = () => {
        setShowConfirmModal(false);
      };
    
      const confirmDeleteHandler = () => {
        setShowConfirmModal(false); //when clicked close the new Modal 
        console.log('DELETING...');
      };

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Modal show={showMap} 
            onCancel={closeMapHandler} 
            header={props.address}
            contentClass="place-item__modal-content"
            footerClass="place-item__modal-actions"
            footer={<Button onClick={closeMapHandler}>Close </Button>}
            >
            <div className='map-container'>
                <Map center={props.coordinates} zoom={16}/>  {/* Should be props.coordinates but we writing default data for now until geocoding solved. */}
            </div>
        </Modal>
      <Modal
        show={showConfirmModal}
        onCancel={cancelDeleteHandler}
        header="Are you entirely sure?"
        footerClass="place-item__modal-actions"
        footer={
          <React.Fragment>
            <Button inverse onClick={cancelDeleteHandler}>
              CANCEL
            </Button>
            <Button danger onClick={confirmDeleteHandler}>
              DELETE
            </Button>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      >
        <p>
          Do you want to proceed and delete this place? Please note that it
          can't be undone thereafter.
        </p>
      </Modal>

        <li className='"place=item'> 
            <Card className="place-item__content">
                <div className='place-item__image'>
                    <img src={props.image} alt={props.title}/>
                </div>
                <div className='place-item__info'>
                    <h2>{props.title}</h2>
                    <h3>{props.address}</h3>
                    <p>{props.description}</p>
                    <p>{props.busrespect}</p>
                </div>
                <div className='place-item__actions'>
                    <Button inverse onClick={openMapHandler}> VIEW ON MAP</Button>
                   {auth.isLoggedIn && (<Button to={`/places/${props.id}`}> EDIT</Button> )}
                  {auth.isLoggedIn &&<Button danger onClick={showDeleteWarningHandler}> DELETE </Button>}
                </div>
            </Card>
        </li>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default PlaceItem;
```

This is auth-context:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext({
    isLoggedIn: false, 
    userId: null,
    login: () => {},
    logout: () => {}});
```

This is is Modal.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Backdrop from './Backdrop';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import './Modal.css';

const ModalOverlay = props => {
    const content =(
        <div className={`modal ${props.className}`} style = {props.style}>
            <header className={`modal__header ${props.headerClass}`}>
                <h2>{props.header}</h2>
            </header>
            <form  
            onSubmit={
                props.onSubmit ? props.onSubmit : event => event.preventDefault()
            }
            >
            <div className={`modal__content ${props.contentClass}`}>
                {props.children}
            </div>
            <footer className={`modal__content ${props.footerClass}`}>
                {props.footer}
            </footer>
            </form>
        </div>
        );
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(content, document.getElementById('modal-hook'));
};

const Modal = props => {
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {props.show && <Backdrop onClick={props.onCancel} />}
        <CSSTransition in={props.show}
        mountOnEnter
        unmountOnExit
        timeout={200}
        classNames="modal"
        >
          <ModalOverlay {...props}/>  
        </CSSTransition>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

Also Trust the routing is correct since I have checked it already and I am just wondering if the logic in REACT with loadedPlaces, PlaceItema and PlaceList makes sense and it working. Let me know please. It will be really helpful.

Summary: Not getting any error but no visual data appears in the scren just the header of my website and the background (rest is empty) even though logic is functional.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const {loadedPlaces, setLoadedPlaces} = useState();
```

change the above line to

```
  const [loadedPlaces, setLoadedPlaces] = useState();
```